# Creating a dynamic HTML table through python looping

Tags: python, html

The only way I could imagine I'd go about making a dynamic table would be to append a multi-line HTML string to another in a loop, but feel there has to be a more effective way. I need to be able to create a table with a set amount of columns and dynamically add more rows.

I'm not even remotely familiar with HTML (or Javascript, if that's going to be necessary).

For example, a query returns a string of information, which is then put in its appropriate place in a list of dictionaries. How would I dynamically make a table for each dictionary instance in list BillingItem?

Comment: Use a templating engine - try Jinja2 or Mako

Comment: Dynamic means the page is getting updated in the browser after it is initially displayed.  It sounds more like you are trying to create static html from a list of data.

Comment: I suppose that's what I was trying to say, I understood 'dynamic' as changing when new information is present.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with the comment that Jinja works well. You could also try https://github.com/Shopify/liquid. It's very flexible.

It might be easier with JS though, seeing as there's a method for this very purpose: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_table_insertrow.asp. It doesn't require much JS knowledge to use, and they include a tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

Jinja sounds like something you should get familiar with.  Basically you can make templates that can be rendered using variables like a list or dictionary.

http://jinja.pocoo.org/